# CSR Bluetooth Dongle can't connect to remote devices

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, drivers, bluetooth

I'm using the Sitecom CN-524 bluetooth dongle with the CSR8510A10 chipset to connect my android tablet to my desktop PC (windows 7 x64). The driver I'm using for the dongle is the Generic Bluetooth Adapter.

Due to other specifications I can only use the bluetooth drivers from broadcom/widcom and the windows generic bluetooth drivers (windows stack) and not the CSR Harmony stack which was delivered with the dongle.
On other discussion I read that this is possible with this dongle.

The problem is that I can pair the devices and detect the tablet in the device manager but after that no connection can be established...I tried it with several devices and with two different dongles, but always had the same problem. Thats why I think it's a driver issue.

I would be very glad about any suggestions, thanks

EDIT: Thanks for your answer. I solved it by using a "plugable" dongle with a broadcom chipset and driver. Now it's working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

First, uninstall everything. You can create a huge mess by pulling in the Microsoft mobile drivers, the drivers from Realtek floating around, the unsupported Harmony etc.

The [Toshiba stack](https://extranet.toshiba-tro.de/en-us/supportquality/bluetoothinfopage/news/downloadtoshiba.aspx), as far as I can see, works. This [blog post](https://extranet.toshiba-tro.de/en-us/supportquality/bluetoothinfopage/news/downloadtoshiba.aspx) recommends adding a DWORD with value 1 to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Toshiba\BluetoothStack\V1.0\Mng`. I did.